# How to use custom deserializer only when default deserializer fails

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I need to create a custom deserializer for arrays because I get them sometimes as strings. I did it but now it can't deserializer normal arrays.

Is there a way to call super deserializer and only when it fails call the custom one?

the code:

```
class ArrayDeserializer : JsonDeserialolizer<Array<Int>>() {

    override fun deserialize(p:JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializtionContext?): Array<Int> {
        return try {
            ctxt?.readValue(p,String::class.java).toArray()
        } catch(e: Exeption) {
            ctxt?.readValue(p, Array<Int>::class.java) ?: throw Error()
        }
    }
}
```

When the Array is in the correct format it throws a `StackoverflowError` exeption.